# Angular UI not updating ngFor after async call

Tags: angular, asynchronous, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic modals to send data back to my component. The data is being sent back correctly, but I cannot get the UI to update for the life of me. The result is the same when using setTimeout, NgZone.run, ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck and ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges

Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import { ModalController } from "@ionic/angular";

import { LinkAccountModalComponent } from "......";

@Component({
    selector: "app-welcome-link-accounts",
    templateUrl: "./link-accounts.page.html",
    styleUrls: ["./link-accounts.page.scss"],
})
export class LinkAccountsPage implements OnInit {
    accounts = [];

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private zone: NgZone,
        private changes: ChangeDetectorRef,
        private modalController: ModalController
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    // Link a new account
    async linkAccount() {
        const modal = await this.modalController.create({
            component: LinkAccountModalComponent
        });

        await modal.present();

        const { data } = await modal.onWillDismiss();

            console.log(data);

            if (data) {
                this.zone.run(() => {
                    this.accounts.push(data); // Doens't work
                    this.accounts = this.accounts.concat(data); // Doesn't work

                    this.changes.markForCheck();
                    this.changes.detectChanges();
                });
            }

            console.log(this.accounts); // Correct
    }

    // Go to next page
    next() {
        this.router.navigate(["/welcome"]);
    }
}
```

This is the part of the template that's not updating:

```
<div *ngFor="let account of accounts">
    {{account.username}}
</div>
```

I posted the example with everything I have tried all together, but I also tried them individually. From what I've read, any one of those should work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do like this instead.

```
modal.onDidDismiss().then(async x => { DO YOUR CODE HERE })
```

You do const DATA = ..... your X variable you ll be the value you pass after you dismiss the modal. I always do like this. I think it's easier to read and work.
Hope it helps you.